# How to fix error "NOT_LOGGED_IN" in Voximplant?

Tags: voximplant

I'm trying to call with Voximplant and get this error. What's wrong?

CallManager: _handleAppStateChange: Current app state changed to inactive
CallManager.js:151 CallManager: _handleAppStateChange: Current app state changed to background
Client.js:563 Client: emit: no handlers for event: ConnectionClosed
CallManager.js:151 CallManager: _handleAppStateChange: Current app state changed to active
how can I make connection again in this situation ?
because of this user are not vaild to call another user. I have to close app and open again to make connection again
backend.js:12688 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
"NOT_LOGGED_IN"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the client state before you call **Client.call** method. If the client state is not logged in, you need to connect and log in again, you can use login with access token to log in "silently", i.e. do not ask user to enter the password